# Is GPG symmetric (decryption) vulnerable?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, file-encryption

Suppose a file (say, a text file source.txt) was encrypted into danger.gpg using GPG symmetric encryption on a compromised device. Since the device is compromised, danger.gpg could have been created by a modified program masquerading as GPG, or the encrypted file could have been modified after running GPG. The attacker knows the encryption key since it was entered on the compromised device in order to create danger.gpg.

If I try to decrypt danger.gpg on a clean device, do I risk infecting it by running the GPG symmetric decryption on the malicious file?

Comment: So the malicious code has been encrypted? That means that it cannot be executed.

Comment: @schroeder: I edited the question to clarify that the malicious code might have been added after encryption, with knowledge of the key/passphrase.

Comment: By your rules, yes.  You've said that the attacker has full control control over the contents of the file, so yes, it could theoretically contain malicious contents.

Comment: but do I risk executing that potentially malicious code in the process of running the decryption?

Answer (score 0):

No, but

#### About [gpg](/questions/tagged/gpg)

By running `gpg` only you just may create a new file. This file could be a virus, hold a virus or point to a virus, but anyway `gpg` won't even try to execute them by himself.

If you're reading this file through a complex integrated system who will try to automatically execute some decrypted data, this could be an issue, but it's not a feature of `gpg`.

Of course, there could be some issues

- **decrypt datas to standard output**, this could permit to trig some *terminal* bugs,
- **bug in gpg binary** I don't even know something like this, but as nothing is perfect, we could imagine some *zero day exploit* able to break gpg himself, but...

#### About [symetric](/questions/tagged/symetric)

Regarding your question, if any host is compromised, encrypted datas comming from this host is subject to caution. Using *symetric* or *asymetric* encryption don't matter... (As using `gpg`, `ssl` or any other way don't matter...)